# How can I make an ImageView move from right to left?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-animation

How can I move an `ImageView` from right to left? However, I don't know about the parameters. This is my code:

```
ImageView enemy2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.enemy2);
TranslateAnimation E2 = new TranslateAnimation(400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(4000);
```

Comment: if you're just trying to move a view (such as a imageview) that should be fine. what is happening?

Comment: Read the guidelines first, this is not an appropriate question format.

Comment: but this code is to move image from left to right, I want my imageView to move from right to left, I am a newbee on android studio, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your numbers around. Read the documentation of the constructor.

```
new TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta
```

replace your numbers with the following.

Comment: no problem! Just next time be sure to format your question correctly :)